# SpringbootTest failing after @Configuration class: Error creating bean with name 'datasource'

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I am trying to execute couple of test cases which were earlier working fine. I recently added a Configuration class which is below :

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {

@Value("${spring.datasource.username:}")
private String username;

@Value("${spring.datasource.url:}")
private String url;

@Bean
@DependsOn("passwordProvider")
public DataSource datasource(PasswordProvider passwordProvider) {
    return DataSourceBuilder
            .create()
            .url(url)
            .username(username)
            .password(new String(passwordProvider.getKeyByName("DB_PASSWORD").getKey()))
            .build();
}
 }
```

Now, all my `SpringbootTests` fail with the below exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$JpaInvokerConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource' defined in class path resource [com/example/configuration/DBConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'datasource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123)
```

Any idea how to get it fixed ? I dont want to provide passwordProvider configuration in test.properties.

Comment: As your own stack says, `Factory method 'datasource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`.  Your bean depends on `passwordProvider` but you're not showing any bean with that name in your `@Configuration`, so it may be that you're not initializing it and so having a null pointer over `passwordProvider.getKeyByName(...)`. In any case, it's impossible to say with what you're providing in the question, we can just guess.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ passwordProvider bean is created by providing configuration in properties file. For test classes, i dont think I should do that. I just wanted to execute the test cases without needing to create dataSource.

Comment: In this case you'll need a test profile, which builds the configuration in a different way than production (for example not creating the beans, or creating mock beans). Check more [about Spring profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: It appears you're re-declaring built-in configuration. Just let `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` do its job.

Answer (score 1):

just mention in the spring boot test and it will load yours configuration class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {DBConfig.class})
public class SpringBootIntegrationTest {
    // ...
}
```